# navigate from usercontrol to page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a usercontrol page with the following code

```
private void StackPanel_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
  Uri uri = new Uri("/News.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

  if (uri != (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).CurrentSource)
  {
    (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(uri);
  }
}
```

But if I navigate to the page it gives a navigation error. But if it navigate to other page it does work. What could be the problem?

Comment: handle exception and tell what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Better use this navigation:

```
private void StackPanel_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
   Uri uri = new Uri("/News.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
   if (uri != (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).CurrentSource)
   {
       NavigationService.navigate(uri);
   }
}
```

and make sure that News.xaml exists and it is in the root directory of the solution.